# Angular 2 i18n issue

Tags: angular

I have some issues with the i18n translation in Angular 2.

I have set up an initial app with the Angular cli, added the i18n text to the header, but when I run `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n` I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: compiler.HtmlParser is not a constructor
    at Function.Extractor.create (C:\Users\Morten\workspace\translate\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extractor.js:57:54)
    at extract (C:\Users\Morten\workspace\translate\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:18:43)
    at Object.main (C:\Users\Morten\workspace\translate\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:30:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Morten\workspace\translate\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\extract_i18n.js:46:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
Extraction failed
```

The versions I'm using are:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.17
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install typings?